# Spring bootstrap + retry + actuator refresh fails the attempt

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-retry

Here is the Spring repo that was used as a reference (same happened to my project): https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-centralized-configuration.git

If I add these dependencies to `complete/configuration-client` module

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-aspects'
implementation 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry'
```

Add such `bootstrap.yml` to the same module:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      retry:
        initial-interval: 2500
        max-attempts: 10
        max-interval: 7000
        multiplier: 1.5
      fail-fast: true # line 1
```

And if I launch config server (`complete/configuration-service`) and the client with above configuration, I will not be able to refresh the client via `actuator/refresh` endpoint. I am getting the following error:

```
2022-01-10 12:11:55.412 ERROR 6868 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configServicePropertySource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/client/ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.LinkageError-->loader 'app' attempted duplicate class definition for org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7f246cf. (org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7f246cf is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:610) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:197) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:114) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:77) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:362) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.LegacyContextRefresher.addConfigFilesToEnvironment(LegacyContextRefresher.java:60) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.LegacyContextRefresher.updateEnvironment(LegacyContextRefresher.java:46) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.ContextRefresher.refreshEnvironment(ContextRefresher.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.ContextRefresher.refresh(ContextRefresher.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.RefreshEndpoint.refresh(RefreshEndpoint.java:41) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:77) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:290) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:373) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.LinkageError-->loader 'app' attempted duplicate class definition for org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7f246cf. (org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7f246cf is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:209) ~[spring-aop-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110) ~[spring-aop-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:461) ~[spring-aop-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:340) ~[spring-aop-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:289) ~[spring-aop-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:437) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 97 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.LinkageError-->loader 'app' attempted duplicate class definition for org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7f246cf. (org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7f246cf is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:578) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:363) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:585) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57) ~[spring-aop-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:206) ~[spring-aop-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 104 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader 'app' attempted duplicate class definition for org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7f246cf. (org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7f246cf is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.System$2.defineClass(System.java:2193) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup$ClassDefiner.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:2446) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup$ClassDefiner.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:2423) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:1850) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:575) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 118 common frames omitted
```

And if I remove `line 1` in `bootstrap.yml`, refresh attempt is successful.

Is there any mistake in Spring retry usage?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. did you find any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Java version. It disappeared when I switched from Java 16 to Java 8.

Comment: Got any solution to your this problem with JDK17 ?

Comment: After my jdk upgrade to 17, i got this error. How to tackle this issue with jdk17 only

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is add the following JVM option. Likely the reason is stricter visibility rules for Java Module System.

> --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: I added this. but still not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add below dependency on complete/configuration-client module since you have already added spring-cloud-starter-config.

`implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'`

You can add your configurations to application.properties file complete/configuration-client like below:

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888/
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

logging.level.root=debug

spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.enabled=true

spring.cloud.config.retry.initial-interval=2500
spring.cloud.config.retry.max-attempts=10
spring.cloud.config.retry.max-interval=7000
spring.cloud.config.retry.multiplier=1.5
```

***bootstrap.yml*** is config file for *spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap* but you do not need this dependency and this config file.
I tested it and worked for me.

Comment: This is not a solution, because the question is about usage of those three modules in a single project, not two out of three.

Answer (score 0):

For me

implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'

this guy caused so much nightmare for me.I have maintained the configs in application.properties as opposed to bootstrap.yml, so no need to add above dependency. If its in classpath, when you hit actuator/refresh, spring will use LegacyContextRefresher instead of  ConfigDataContextRefresher. What was happening in case of LegacyContextRefresher , the envrionment variable internally used as StandardEnvironment instead of ApplicationServletEnvironment, so properties are not getting read from application.properties.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).